# Retrieve value from an Object / Multi-Dimensional Array Received from a Web Service

Tags: php, object, multidimensional-array

I am calling a web service, and receive this response which I can see using var_dump. How do I get the Name value? Also, what structure is this?

```
object(DescribeEntityTypeResponse)#2 (1) {
["DescribeEntityTypeResult"]=>
object(DescribeEntityTypeResult)#6 (1) {
["EntityTypes"]=>
object(ArrayOfEntityType)#7 (1) {
  ["EntityType"]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    object(EntityType)#8 (3) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(0)
      ["Name"]=>
      string(7) "Contact"
      ["Type"]=>
      string(4) "Base"
    }
    [1]=>
    object(EntityType)#9 (3) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(0)
      ["Name"]=>
      string(7) "Company"
      ["Type"]=>
      string(4) "Base"
    }
    [2]=>
    object(EntityType)#10 (3) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(0)
      ["Name"]=>
      string(8) "Prospect"
      ["Type"]=>
      string(4) "Base"
    }
    [3]=>
    object(EntityType)#11 (3) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(0)
      ["Name"]=>
      string(7) "Visitor"
      ["Type"]=>
      string(4) "Base"
    }
    [4]=>
    object(EntityType)#12 (3) {
      ["ID"]=>
      int(0)
      ["Name"]=>
      string(17) "ProcessedActivity"
      ["Type"]=>
      string(4) "Base"
    }
  }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Do you want _all_ the name values in an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
foreach($result->DescribeEntityTypeResult->EntityTypes->EntityType as $entityType) {
    $name = $entityType['Name'];
}
```

However the objects may have methods() to access these properties.

Comment: Thanks - after digging around a bit more, I did find a method that allows me to access the properties.